# How can I unload multiple registry hives in PowerShell? (Access Denied error)

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry

I've loaded dozens of registry hives as `HKLM:\temp_$username\`. Now when I try to run `ls HKLM:\temp_* | %{reg unload $_}` I get `ERROR: Access is denied.`

I'm running PowerShell with elevated priveleges and tried restarting PowerShell ISE to clear out variables. I still receive the error. I can unload the hives using the GUI, and I can run the command for individual hives (`reg unload HKLM\temp_jimbob`), so I'm a little perplexed as to why the command simply will not run for multiple hives.

What is causing the access denied error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ls HKLM:\temp_*` is what's causing the "access denied" error. Running this command is leaving every desired registry hive open and inaccessible to the `reg` program. It's sort of a catch-22: without the list the hives cannot be unloaded, but the list cannot be used once obtained.

To work around this, use the Name property, which is a `[System.String]` versus a `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]`:

```
$foo = ls "hklm:\temp_*" | Select -ExpandProperty Name
foreach($bar in $foo)
{
    reg unload $bar
}
```

Note that it *must* be two lines. Trying to pipe the output of Select will result in the same error.

If you still receive errors, it might be worth running garbage collection using `[gc]::collect()`, picking through `Get-Variables`, or restarting PowerShell ISE.